# kvm hypervisor kernel panic

Tags: kvm-virtualization, kernel, kernel-panic, hypervisor

My kvm hypervisor had been running with 20+ vps guests for a few months. But a few days ago it went to kernel panic. There were no abnormal operation that I found would cause the problem, except that the hypervisor was deleting a guest and shrubbing the corresponding logical volume at the time. Is this a hypervisor bug? How to fix it?

```
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: BUG: Bad page map in process crond  pte:00000f00     pmd:436a14058
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: addr:00008cbbca104512 vm_flags:08514270 anon_vma:(null) mapping:ffff41521ab409e0 index:16a
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: vma->vm_ops->fault: filemap_fault+0x0/0x500
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: vma->vm_file->f_op->mmap: ext4_file_mmap+0x0/0x60 [ext4]
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: Pid: 22373, comm: crond Not tainted 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: Call Trace:
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8523ef18>] ? print_bad_pte+0x1d8/0x290
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8521b970>] ? generic_file_aio_read+0x380/0x700
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8523f03b>] ? vm_normal_page+0x6b/0x70
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8524179f>] ? unmap_vmas+0x61f/0xc30
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: [<ffffffff852476d7>] ?Apr 12 05:44:03 vps kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

Comment: Memory failure? What does SEL (System Event Log) says?

Comment: 'dmidecode -t system' shows that no error is detected

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug:

```
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: BUG: Bad page map in process crond  pte:00000f00     pmd:436a14058
```

You're running RHEL:

```
Apr 12 05:33:51 vps kernel: Pid: 22373, comm: crond Not tainted 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1
```

First, open a ticket with RH. If that doesn't bear fruit, update the kernel and pray it doesn't happen again. There's no "magic fix" to prevent this in the future.